# Does free trial period for In App Purchases in iOS only work once?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, ios11

We are integration IAP in our iOS11 app and want to give new users some start offerings with a long free trial period.

My implementation alternatives are:

- Use auto-renewable subscription with a generous free trial (like 2 months for monthly subscription), and rely on Apple that a user that cancels can't restart and get 2 months again. Is this correct?

or

- Make two IAPs, present the one with free trial to new users and present the one without free trails to a user that has canceled or stopped the free trail version. But users might find the IAP on App store (specially now when Apple will start feature IAP) and buy it anyway?

What is the best thing to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm managing an application with InApp Purchase and auto-renewable subscription. 
As far as I know, InApp Purchase is linked to user AppStore account, and free trial can be consume only once per account.

If you present the same product after a free trial period, the user will resume your auto-renewable subscription and not benefit the free trial again.

So in my mind the first option is the best.

However if you would like to implement the second one, you should know that the new IAP management feature in your product store page allow you to show and hide the subscriptions you want. 
For more information about this new feature, take a look at the WWDC video : [What's New in StoreKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/303/)

Comment: Thanks for the link and for the clarification of the trial period. I'm probably going for the first option, even if it's good to know that we can make more start offers alternatives and then hide them and only show regular ones once the user has used one of those options

Comment: As @vmeyer said option 1 should be a better option, but you must be wary of these gotchas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55953331/preventing-trial-period-fraudulent-in-ios-in-app-purchases